# Prove that $MN=\frac{1}{2}(AB+BC+CA)$

Tags: proof-writing, triangles, quadrilateral

As I was doing a question on quadrilateral, I found out this one, which I couldn't find to relate with any properties of a quadrilateral. It seems there is a trapezium in between, but it's quite unclear to me how to establish a relation. Please help if you can.

[A diagram of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0d8XN.jpg)

It is not given that:

1. $ABC$ is equilateral.
2. $MN$ bisects angle $M$ or angle $N$.

Comment: @S Roy I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Answer (score 2):

Let the lines AM and AN cut the line BC at P and Q,  respectively
Since triangle ABP(AB=BP) and triangle ACQ(AC=CQ) are isosceles triangles, M and N are the midpoint of AP and AQ,  respectively.
Then by Midpoint Theorem
$$MN=\frac{1}{2}PQ=\frac{1}{2}(PB+BC+CQ)=\frac{1}{2}(AB+BC+CA)$$